# Did Peter ever save that girl?

Tags: heroes

In the second season of Heroes, Peter ends up taking him and this girl into the future, where a virus has nearly wiped out the human race.  He ends up coming back to present time, and ends up preventing that future.  Was it ever showed that the girl was saved, or was it left for speculation?

Comment: It was actually season two of Heroes that was cut short, due to the writer's guild strike.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, they never returned to that storyline.  It was dropped and we never saw or heard of that girl again.  As such, it's unknown if she was saved, but as the plague was prevented she should be safe in the new future.

Comment: Well... not necessarily....

Comment: Arguably if that plague never happened, she was dropped off in a timeline that was likely prevented from occurring altogether, and probably no longer exists.  ...or something

Comment: From what I've read, they wanted to go back to that, but isn't that around the time of the writer strike?

Comment: @Rob - yep, a whole volume was cut (and another moved off to the third season).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's around when I stopped watching, too. I've heard it was a good choice.

Comment: @Rob It was part of season 2, which was cut short due to the strike.  That ended up being a pretty weird season as a result.

Comment: @Rob, I like Heroes, even with it's gaping plot holes.

Comment: Didnt Hiro change the future at the start of season 3 and wipe all of that out?  The only consistant would be Peter because he absorbed Hiro's power and someone can transit the realities too?  That was the theory we had when i quit watching... I relasized there were too many cool guys trying to jump carniverous fish on waterskis ...

Comment: I rather than she is lost in the future I choose to believe that she still exist in that future. Although it has been changed into alternative future line

Comment: Does any one know why they never revisited Season 2 volume 2 and tie up the story? I know they chose to bring volume 3 (villians) over into season 3, but why didn't they carry on after the writers guild strike?

Comment: @Jared No, they never did revist the Season 2 plots.

Comment: @Keen - Hey Keen I was asking if anybody knew *why*, not if they did, cheers.